# A column was not found in laravel query builder

Tags: jquery, laravel, query-builder

i am writing a query for getting all the type which have properties

```
    DB::table('property_types')        
    ->join('properties',"property_types.id",'=',"properties.property_type")
    ->select('property_types.id','property_types.types')
    ->get();
```

column and all related field inside the table but it's throwing error

```
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
  'properties.property_type=property_types.id' in 'on clause' 
  (SQL: select * from `property_types` inner join `properties` 
  on `properties`.`property_type=property_types`.`id` = ``)
```

Comment: Can you share also your table's structure ?

Comment: if you're 100% sure the fields exist on the table also make sure the correct db connection is used. Run something like `DB::table('property_types')->first()` to check wheter the table is found

Comment: I don't think your code matches the expected error, can you rerun and check the exception is the same?